# Moving options menu to another view

Tags: android, layout, view, options-menu

I am trying to display the options menu in another place but the ActionBar, is it is hidden.
I have no clue on how to do it nor I find any function to do such things.

I am using Theme.Light.NoTitleBar as theme/style, but still I'd like to have the menu somewhere else, be it a View or a Layout.

Does anyone have any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use Android support library , which would enable you to use Action Bar in Android Version 11.0 and above. You would also require to use `Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar` as your application theme to make action bar visible.

After you do this , you may create menu xml file ad inflate it in `onCreateOptionsMenu()` function , and you can then access Action Bar like this : `getActionBar()` in your activity.